# Katalon Studio Database checkpoint for Stored Procedure not working

Tags: katalon-studio

I am using latest version of Katalon Studio for our Android mobile app Automation.

But Database checkpoint for SQL Stored Procedure is not working at all with Katalon.
By providing correct query and parameter for Stored Procedure execution i am still getting error as "Wrong number of Parameter" error and unable to work with Database checkpoint for Stored Procedure execution using Katalon.

Please help.

Comment: Can you add your execution log, please?

Answer (score 0):

in DB define view based on your Stored procedure, then use view as Database checkpoint in Katalon

Comment: Its our product database so we cant change anything in database.Any other way ?

Comment: what Database is it? (Oracle, Postgre, MySQL)?

Comment: its MySQL database

Comment: can you share code you are using to call stored proc.? i found this article that describes how to execute stored proc using MySQL JDBC from java (and thus groovy)
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/calling-mysql-stored-procedures-from-jdbc/